WSL not compatible with windows version: "This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running."
After some issues with running commands in my Ubuntu zsh terminal, I tried a fix and now it says my WSL isn't compatible with my version of Windows.
So I've been trying to setup ubuntu on my Windows x64 machine.
Everything was going fine, WSL was setup correctly annd I was able to run commands in my Ubuntu terminal.
However, I was coming accross this error when I was running some commands (like flutter, node, etc) in that terminal:
env: bash\r: No such file or directory

I was trying to troubleshoot how to fix this issue when I came accross this stack overflow discussion: [env: bash\r: No such file or directory duplicate.
The first answer seemed to not apply and it seemed like maybe the second answer was the next best thing to try out. So I did and ran
sudo apt-get install -y dos2unix # Installs dos2unix Linux
sudo find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \; # recursively removes windows related stuff

This took about an hour to complete, and when it finished, I restarted Ubuntu and it immediately crashed.
Starting it up again, it gives me this error: wsl error I'm getting
I opened powershell to try and run any wsl commands and I get the following error:

This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

